# Want to show TFS history

Tags: tfs

I want to show TFS history with the following columns:

- Date and time,
- Filesname,
- username,
- Checkin Comments.

My requirement is want to see the report weekly based on dates.

Comment: Hi welcome on SO. Please check [ask] , [mcve]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is want to see the report weekly based on dates.

There is no such out of box way to get the TFS workitem history directly. Because all the results of the query are workitems list not the details of workitems.

To get the details of the workitem history, you could use the API to output the workitem all changes history:

[TFS API: TFS Work Item All Changes History](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117462/TFS-API-TFS-Work-Item-All-Changes-History)

Then export this grid in format you want and save it locally.

Or, you can use Power BI Desktop to resolve this issue, you can check following blog, it should give you some help:

[Querying the VSTS Work Items API directly from Power BI](https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/07/querying-the-vsts-work-items-api-directly-from-power-bi/)

Hope this helps.